# Simplifying two fractions on top of a third fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

How would I go about simplifying this fraction:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{a}}{x - a}$$

I've looked at similar questions such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395720/simplifying-fractions-with-fractions) one but still can't seem to figure this one out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: the number $1$ can be written many different ways and any expression multiplied by $1$ does not change the value of the expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}{x-a}=\frac{\frac{a-x}{ax}}{x-a}=\frac{a-x}{ax} \cdot \frac{1}{x-a}=\frac{-1}{xa}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Expanding
$$\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{a}}{x-a}$$
by $a\cdot x$ yields
$$\frac{a-x}{ax(x-a)}=-\frac{1}{ax}.$$

Michael